# Create aMule daemon systemd .service file

Tags: systemd, services, daemon, init.d

I recently moved to **Raspbian Jessie** on my RPi and now I'd like to move all my services from `init.d` to `systemd`.

aMule daemon it is now working with init.d but I want to move the script to a `amule-daemon.service` file, to add some dependencies from other services, like `autofs`.

My actual init.d script for aMule is this:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          amule-daemon
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Should-Start:      $network
# Should-Stop:       $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Daemonized version of aMule.
# Description:       Starts the aMule daemon with the user specified in
#                    /etc/default/amule-daemon.
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

PROGNAME=amuled
DESC="aMule daemon"
PKGNAME="amule-daemon"
DAEMON=/usr/bin/amuled
WEB=/usr/bin/amuleweb
WEB_OPTS="--quiet --config-file=/etc/.aMule/remote.conf"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$PKGNAME
WRAPPER=/usr/share/amule/amuled_home_wrapper.sh

[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0
[ -r /etc/default/$PKGNAME ] && . /etc/default/$PKGNAME

. /lib/init/vars.sh # has VERBOSE
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ -z "$AMULED_USER" ]; then
    log_warning_msg \
    "Not starting $DESC, AMULED_USER not set in /etc/default/$PKGNAME."
    exit 0
fi

do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec $DAEMON --user "$AMULED_USER" --chuid "$AMULED_USER" --test  >/dev/null || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec $WRAPPER --user "$AMULED_USER" --chuid "$AMULED_USER" >/dev/null || return 2
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --exec $WEB --user "$AMULED_USER" --chuid "$AMULED_USER" -- $WEB_OPTS & >/dev/null
}

do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry="TERM/30/KILL/5" --exec $DAEMON --user "$AMULED_USER" --chuid "$AMULED_USER" 
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry="TERM/30/KILL/5" --exec $WEB --user "$AMULED_USER" --chuid "$AMULED_USER"
    return "$?"
}


case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$PROGNAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && \
            log_progress_msg "(already running)" && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$PROGNAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0 | 1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2)     [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$PROGNAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0 | 1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1; exit 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1; exit 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

As you can see, it is configured to launch aMule daemon with some options:

- run with specific user `amuled`
- run web interface `amuleweb`
- load web interface options from `remote.conf`
- set home directory configuration using `amuled_home_wrapper.sh`

and it works perfectly.

How can I move all this options into the .service file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final working solution was to **write a systemd unit file that executes the init.d script**, without convert the entire script.

This is the systemd unit for aMule.

```
[Unit]
Description=aMule Daemon
After=network.target
Requires=autofs.service

[Service]
User=amuled
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/amule-daemon start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/amule-daemon stop
ExecReload=/etc/init.d/amule-daemon restart

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

NOTE: The `Requires=autofs.service` directive is not mandatory. It is there because I use `autofs` to mount a NFS drive for the service which is configured to read/write on it.

Answer (score 0):

On debian/ubuntu edit `/etc/default/amule-daemon` by doing this for example `sudo nano /etc/default/amule-daemon` and put `AMULED_USER="user1"` (if your current user is user1)

Then just restart the daemon: `sudo systemctl restart amule-daemon.service`